# Capturing video of Mac window

Tags: macos

Mac has a neat little feature where I can (while grabbing a portion of the screen) hit spacebar and click on a window to capture it (and the surrounding shadow), for example:

[image]

I've searched for this on Google, but its stupid algorithm keeps searching for similar words, even when I put it in quotes (like `mac "record window only"`). I want to capture a video of a window only (including cursor of course).

How do I do this? What application do I use?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Quicktime Player. File->New Screen Recording. You can select a portion of the screen, but spacebar doesn't work to select the whole window, you have to drag a frame around the window manually. You can trim the video afterwards, if you selected an area too big though. If you want to google, use "quicktime record window".

Comment: I am looking to capture the shadow as well, for a 'true' window-only recording. This solution also will not work if you move or resize the window.

Comment: Well.. google "osx screencasting window" or something like that. Capturing the window only with shadow should be easy - put it on a white background and record the area around it as well. Resizing a window during a video recording doesn't make too much sense. Video formats don't allow changing the frame size during playback AFAIK, so there's not much sense in recording that way. You'll have to cut your video afterwards, if you want to do what you write.

Comment: I just remember how I did it some years ago - use spaces and a white desktop background with only the window you have. Then quicktime it.